# Dropdown in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In my MVC application, I need to add a dropdown that would show a list of domain names.

I already have a ViewModel that contains multiple properties. I am not sure what the sequence of the steps should be:

1. Add a new property to my `ViewModel`? What should be the type? List?
2. Define a method that populates the above property with values.
3. Use that property in the View? Use `HTML.DropdownFor`?

I know I should put some code in my Question, but right now I am having difficulty getting started with this...

**EDIT:**
Added the following property to the ViewModel:

```
 public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> DomainList { get; set; }
```

and implemented a method to return a list of Domains:

```
internal static List<Domain> FetchAllDomains()
```

Next in my controller action, I have:

```
var domains = FetchAllDomains().Select(d => d.DomainName);
return new EmailModel() {DomainList = domains };
```

But I get the following error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'.
>   An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> 1) Add a new property to my ViewModel? What should be the type? List?

You need 2 properties to be more precise: an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` to hold all the available options and a scalar property to hold the selected value

> 2) Define a method that populates the above property with values.

Yes.

> 3) Use that property in the View? Use HTML.DropdownFor?

No, not in the view. The view doesn't call any methods. A view works with the view model. It is the responsibility of the controller to pass a properly filled view model to the view.

So for example:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string SelectedValue { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Values { get; set; }

    ... some other properties that your view might need
}
```

and then a controller action that will populate this view model:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new MyViewModel();
    model.Values = new[]
    {
        new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "item 1" },
        new SelectListItem { Value = "2", Text = "item 2" },
        new SelectListItem { Value = "3", Text = "item 3" },
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

and finally the strongly typed view in which you will display the dropdown list:

```
@model MyViewModel
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedValue, Model.Values)
```

---

UPDATE:

According to your updated question you are have an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` property on your view model to which you are trying to assign a value of type `IEnumerable<string>` which obviously is impossible. You could convert this to an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` like this:

```
var domains = FetchAllDomains().Select(d => new SelectListItem
{
    Value = d.DomainName,
    Text = d.DomainName
});
return new EmailModel { DomainList = domains };
```

Comment: I implemented a method that returns a list of domain names like:  var domains = FetchAllDomains().Select(d=>d.DomainName);
            
return new EmailModel(campaign) { DomainList = domains };         But I get the error : Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: Please update your question to show your full code. The comments section should be used only for comments as code snippets are not properly formatted and are not readable.

Comment: OK. Updated the original post

Comment: @DarinDimitrov hi darin can you check this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14055286/getting-an-error-while-using-dropdown-in-mvc

Answer (score 3):

If you do not mind, I'll show you an example list of exams

```
public class SomeClass
{
    //Properties

    public int ExamId { get; set; }
    public SelectList ExamList { get; set; }
}
```

Helper:

```
public static void PopulateExamList(MarkEditViewModel model,
    List<Exam> examList)
{
    model.ExamList = new SelectList(examList, "Id", "ExamName");
}
```

You must to add to marks, in my example, list of all exams. After this in View you will get a dropdown list of exams
And View (foreach every element in Model):

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ExamId,
                                        Model.ExamList,
                                        "Choose exam")
```

Comment: I'm trying to populate a `Driver Type` drop down list in my Driver view. User should be able to select the driver from that drop down list when adding drivers. I tried to implement your code. But it gives a null reference exception. What would be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Once you have the list on your controller pass it to the view (as model or using ViewBag) and then use the helper:

```
Html.DropDownList(
    string name,
    IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList,
    string optionLabel,
    object htmlAttributes)
```

Or (MVC 3)

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Property.ID,
    new SelectList(model.PropertyList, "ID", "Type"))
```

Answer (score 0):

In your ViewModel

```
public class ViewModelClass
{
    public string DomainName { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> DomainList
    {
        get
        {
            return GetDomainNames()  //your method to get domain names
             .Select(d => new SelectListItem() { Text = d, Value = d });
        }
    }
}
```

your strongly typed view

```
@model ViewModelClass

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.DomainName, Model.DomainList)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes you need a property in  your model to handle the value of the `DropDownList`
2. Depends, normally could be an Integer that refers to the value of the DropDownlist
   The List that you're going to used to populate elements could be define as a element in a ViewBag, or an Another Attribute in your model
3. The razor Syntax depends entirely of the what do you try achieve you should use `@Html.DropDownListFor()` refers to an attribute of your model for guarantee that the view was stronglyTyped

Answer (score 0):

You are in the right track, Have 2 properties in your ViewModel. One to hold the list of items and other for the selected Item Id from the UI

```
public class ProductViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Items { get; set; }
    public string SelectedItemId { get; set; }
    //Other Properties
}
```

And in your Get Action method, Return the ViewModel with the data

```
 public ActionResult Index()
 {
    var objProduct = new ProductViewModel();
    objProduct.Items = new[]
    {
          new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "Domain 1" },
          new SelectListItem { Value = "3", Text = "Domain 2" },
          new SelectListItem { Value = "3", Text = "Domain 3" }
    };
    // can replace the above line with loading data from Data access layer.
    return View(objProduct);
}
```

and in your view which is strongly typed to ProductViewModel

```
@model ProductViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{ 
  @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedItemId, new SelectList(Model.Items,"Value","Text"), "Select..")
  <input type="submit" value="save" />
}
```

and in your HTTPpost Action, You will have the selected value available

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(ProductViewModel model)
{
 //  check model.SElectedItemId here

}
```