# Trouble with MVC 4 DropDownListFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am having trouble with displaying `Dropdownlist` in MVC 4 application.
It looks straightforward, However something is still missing which is not getting hold of.

ViewModel

```
public class vendorModel
{
    public int vendorID { get; set; }
    public int vendorTypeID { get; set; }
    public string vendorName { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<vendorTypeModel> vendorTypes { get; set; }
}

public class vendorTypeModel
{
    public int vendorTypeID { get; set; }
    public string vendorTypeName { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
 [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Vendor() {
        vendorModel oVendor = new vendorModel();
        oVendor.vendorTypes = blVendor.getAllVendorTypes();
        return View(oVendor);
    }
```

`getAllVendorTypes` Method
This is where I am fetching records from database and building and returning a `List<vendorTypeModel>` object.
and Finally on View am using following code.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.vendorTypeID, new SelectList(Model.vendorTypes,"vendorTypeID","vendorTypeName"))
```

What am I doing wrong? I am getting following results on screen.

[image]

Instead of names of vendors.

Please suggest whats wrong with my code.

Comment: It suggests your `getAllVendorTypes()` method is wrong and not returning the correct data.

Comment: Can you please set a break point on the line of "return View(oVendor);" and check for the the vendorTypes before the line get executed and make sure you have correct results as the vendorTypes in oVendor object. Let me know what you observe. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that `oVendor.vendorTypes = blVendor.getAllVendorTypes();` may return a wrong list back. Set a breakpoint and check the `oVendor.vendorTypes` please.

Comment: Yes, There was an error in getAllVendorTypes method.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/15195354/6741868, you could try alternative syntax such as:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.vendorTypeID, Model.vendorTypes.Select(vendor => new SelectListItem()
{
    Text = vendor.vendorTypeName,
    Value = vendor.vendorTypeID
})
```