# How do I make different check boxes appear depending on what is selected from a drop down list

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I am fairly new to c# and I am looking to create a form in c# that has a drop down with a list of rooms, from the drop down selection, I would like to populate, in the same c# form a list of checkboxes of duties for that specific room, each drop down room selection would have a different set of duties tied to it

```
<div id="rc" class="saniHide">
        <form method="post" asp-page-handler="rcForm">
            <Label>Please Select a Room</Label><br />
            <select required class="drop" id="room" name="Room">
                <option value="">Select Room</option>
                <option value="1">Twister and Trim Room</option>
            </select>
        </form>
    </div>
```

so i would like the form to show the drop down list then to right of the drop down a list of checkboxes, what or how is the best way of doing this?

Comment: What have you tried on the C# side? What platform are you using? WebForms? MVC? We need more details surrounding the issue

Comment: Can you make your requirement more clear? So if you select a room from the drop down then you want to show the checkboxes which are related to that room. Right?

Comment: @Amir yes that is correct

Comment: @Dortimer I am using the Razor with mvc

Comment: @MikeDonati you should include tags for that in the future to keep it as narrow as possible. We still need more detail. Are you binding a model to the form? Where do the values for the drop down come from? Check out this link for info on building drop downs with C# in the view: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15195256/mvc-dropdownlistfor-basics