# How to query database for put into Dropdownlist MVC razor ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

### How to query database for put into Dropdownlist MVC razor ASP.NET C

I would like to put this query into drowdownlistt. I tried many way to do that but I always get something like "{SELECT 
    [Extent1].[ID] AS [ID], . . . (@p__linq__0 IS NULL))}"

but I want to get the value(the result) of this query

so, how can I solve this problem?

here is my query:

```
var listSector = db.SectorUserLinks.Include(s => s.Sector).Where(s => s.UserId == USERID);
```

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To stop the query from showing you the SQL put `ToList()` at the end, like this

`var listSector = db.SectorUserLinks.Include(s => s.Sector).Where(s => s.UserId == USERID).ToList();`

Comment: then how to put them into dropdownlist?

Comment: @anin see the accepted answer on the following post for an example of how to bind the dropdown list http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10484774/dropdown-in-mvc